# urlでギリシア文字を指定可能ですか？ 例えば「index-α.html」「index-β.html」など

Tags: http, url

**urlでギリシア文字を指定可能ですか？**
・仕様は、RFC 3986 ？

**アルファベット小文字とは、ラテン小文字のこと？**
・ギリシア文字は含まれない？

**リンク先に下記記述があるのですが、これはエンコード前の話ですか？**
・それともurlだからエンコードは関係ない？
・[2003年にはアラビア語やキリル文字、ギリシア文字、そして漢字が使えるようになった](https://eset-info.canon-its.jp/malware_info/special/detail/151001.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

URLとURI([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986))は別物です。ただURLはURIの一種(subset)ですので、その仕様に従います(RFC 3986 §1.1.3)。
URIで使える文字はreservedとunreservedに分けられ、それらは以下のように定義されていて、reservedは文字列の区切りなどとして使われることが想定されています(RFC 3986 §2.2-3)。

```
reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
...
unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
...
ALPHA       = %41-%5A / %61-%7A = "A"-"Z" / "a"-"z" 
DIGIT       = %30-%39           = "0"-"9"
```

なのでギリシャ文字を直接書くことはできません、パーセントエンコーディングを使う必要があります。変換順序としては[RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629)にそってUTF-8オクテットに変換されたのち、上記unreservedの文字を除いて1バイトごとに16進数で表し`%`を前につけます。
`index-α.html`の場合、αはUTF-8では`0xCE 0xB1`なので`index-%CE%B1.html`となりますhttp://example.com/index-%CE%B1.html(ブラウザによってはαとして表示してくれたりしますが)。

[リンクされた記事](https://eset-info.canon-its.jp/malware_info/special/detail/151001.html)が話しているのはドメイン名(IPアドレスに解決する必要がある)の話で、これはURLとは別のレベルです。ドメイン名も元はASCII文字のみでしたがpunycode([RCF 3492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492))によってUnicodeの**一部**を含めれるようになりました。ブラウザでは漢字などに見えますが実態は`xn--`で始まるただのASCII文字列です。

以下のURLは両方`http://日本語.jp/`をさしますが、上はドメイン名をpunycode encode、下はpercent encodeしてあります。パーセントエンコードした方はブラウザが1度UTF-8にしたのちpunycodeにしてサーバーに送っています。

http://xn--wgv71a119e.jp/
http://%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E.jp/

Comment: 「ブラウザによってはαとして表示してくれたりします」。なるほど、「実際のブラウザ表示」と「仕様」は必ずしも一致しないわけですね。「ドメイン名(IPアドレスに解決する必要がある)の話で、これはURLとは別のレベル」。なるほど、URL構成要素なので同じと考えていたのですが、ドメインにはIPアドレス変換という重要な役割があるため、別途仕様が定められているわけですね。また,「punycode encode」については、(ブラウザの代わりに)予め自分で変換しても良いわけですね。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 3):

> **urlでギリシア文字を指定可能ですか？**
> ・仕様は、RFC 3986 ？

[HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/references.html#biblio-url)での話なら指定可能です。仕様は、[RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987)です。

```
   iunreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~" / ucschar

   ucschar        = %xA0-D7FF / %xF900-FDCF / %xFDF0-FFEF
                  / %x10000-1FFFD / %x20000-2FFFD / %x30000-3FFFD
                  / %x40000-4FFFD / %x50000-5FFFD / %x60000-6FFFD
                  / %x70000-7FFFD / %x80000-8FFFD / %x90000-9FFFD
                  / %xA0000-AFFFD / %xB0000-BFFFD / %xC0000-CFFFD
                  / %xD0000-DFFFD / %xE1000-EFFFD
```

[HTTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540)での話ならまだRFC 3986参照になっているようで、指定不可能です。（このままなのかも？）

なので、Webクライアントは、パス部分を（ページのエンコーディングに関わらず）UTF-8に変換後にパーセントエンコーディングしてWebサーバーに送信しています。

- [An Introduction to Multilingual Web Addresses](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/)

  - [Resolving a path](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/#iritechnical)
  - [I18N Tests: Resource identifiers 3](https://www.w3.org/International/tests/test-incubator/oldtests/sec-iri-3)

    ```
      <a href="/International/articles/idn-and-iri/JP納豆/引き割り納豆.html">
    ```
- [URL Standard](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/)

  - [URL parsing > path state](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#path-state)

Comment: [W3CのHTML5のURL](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/urls.html#terminology-0)だとIRI([RFC 3987](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3987))が使えるのはURLが書かれたDocumentがUTF-8かUTF-16の時のみってあったりして、IRIが仕様的に使えるかどうかって状況で微妙に違ってきますよね。ちなみにリンクされた「I18N Tests: Resource identifiers 3」はXHTML1.0をShift-JISで書いてるので、そこでは良いのでしょう。

Comment: @packet0 4つの条件のうち1つ以上を満たせばいいとあるので、エスケープされていない非ASCII文字がクエリ文字列に含まれていなければ、Documentのエンコーディングに関わらずIRIはvalidかと。

Comment: @unarist うわ、ほんとですね。あとコメントでリンクしたのはdraft版で最終版だとWHATWGのURL参照するようにって書いてあります...ただそっちの§Goalを見ると今後URIやIRIを参照しない方向に持っていくってあるので、HTMLの場合独自仕様ってことになるのでしょうかね